# unable to update axios url parameter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-state

I am building an app using the github jobs api (https://jobs.github.com/api) in react . The first time I run my app I get the titles of all jobs of the first page of the api .
[image]

When I click on the button above I want to append the results of the next page of the api to my current job titles.I use `axios` to fetch the job titles  from the github api and the `useState` hook to change my page . I store  my `page` and `currentJobs` using the Context Api .

The problem is that when I change the  page variable , the base axios url does not change ! So I get the same results as my first request .

My code :

LoadMore.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import {useAppContext} from '../Components/AppContext';

export default function LoadMore() {
  const {page,setPage} = useAppContext(); //gets page,setPage context variables 

  const nextPage= ()=>{
    setPage(page+1);
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick = {()=>nextPage()} variant="contained" color="secondary">
      Load More 
    </Button>
  )
}
```

My custom hook to fetch github :

useFetchJobs.js

```
import {React,useEffect, useState , useReducer} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useAppContext} from './AppContext';


const ACTIONS = {
  MAKE_REQUEST:'make-request',
  GET_DATA:'get-data',
  GOT_ERROR:'got-error'
}

const reducer = (state,action) =>{
  switch (action.type){
    case ACTIONS.MAKE_REQUEST:
      return {...state,loading:true , jobs:[]};
    case ACTIONS.GET_DATA:
      return { ...state, loading:false , jobs:action.payload.jobs};
    case ACTIONS.GOT_ERROR:
      return {...state,loading:false, jobs:[] , error:action.payload.error}
    default:
      return state
  }
}


export default function useFetchJobs(params,page) {
  
  const {currentJobs,setCurrentJobs} = useAppContext(); //the current jobs on my page 
  const BASE_URL = `https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://jobs.github.com/positions.json`; //the base url 
  const [state,dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {jobs: [] , loading:true});

  useEffect(()=>{

    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    dispatch( {type:ACTIONS.MAKE_REQUEST} );
    console.log('page is ' +page); //PAGE IS SET CORRECTLY !
    //MY PROBLEM : THE BASE URL DOES NOT CHANGE ON PAGE CHANGE !!!
    axios.get(BASE_URL,{
      cancelToken: source.token,
      params:{markdown:true , page :page, ...params}
    }).then((res)=>{
      setCurrentJobs([...currentJobs,res.data]); //UPDATE CURRENT JOBS  
      dispatch({type:ACTIONS.GET_DATA , payload:{jobs: res.data} })
    }).catch(e=>{
      if(axios.isCancel(e)) return 
      dispatch({type:ACTIONS.GOT_ERROR ,payload:{error:e } })
    })
    
    return ()=>{
      source.cancel();
    }

  },[page,params]);
  
  return {state};
 
}
```

My JobList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import useFetchJobs from '../Components/useFetchJobs';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Job from '../Components/Job';
import LoadMore from '../Components/LoadMore';
import {useAppContext} from '../Components/AppContext';

export default function JobList() {

  const {params,page,currentJobs,setCurrentJobs} = useAppContext(); //the current jobs are the jobs displayed 
  const {state:{loading,error}} = useFetchJobs(params,page); //fetch jobs from custom hook 
   

  return (
    <Container>
     {loading && <p>Loading ...</p>}
     {error && <p>Error : Could not load results </p>}
     { (typeof currentJobs !== "undefined") &&
       currentJobs.flat().map((job)=>{
         return <Job key = {job.id} job={job} />
       })
     }
     { (!loading && currentJobs.length>=1 ) && <LoadMore />}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

So when I click on load more the page normally switched but the axios url stays the same and gets the same results ! I check this using axios interceptors.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config=>{
     //returns correct base but not changed url  
     console.log(`the page is ${config.params.page} the url is {config.url}`);
     return config;
   },error=>{
     return Promise.reject(error);
   });
```

I would appreciate your help with this .

Comment: have you tried `params:{...params, markdown:true , page :page}`

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Same result

Comment: And if you create `params` before making request, and log it into console, will it have `page` set correctly?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova params is not the issue I believe . It is an empty object {} right now . The page is the problem

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova In my JobList.js I tried  useEffect(()=>{
     console.log('page is ' +page);
  },[page]);  The result was the same .

Comment: If you pass correct `params` to `axios.get` you should get the correct URL, unless there is a bug in `axios`, which is unlikely.  Have you checked the URL btw?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229286/discussion-between-vasilis-123-and-nadia-chibrikova).